# How to load external .js to the body of a Wordpress Page?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to add this script to a PAGE on wordpress theme.
I don't want it at header or footer, i want it in the body of the specific page i created in Wordpress.

This code works if it was in a normal html page on a folder where Wordpress is not installed.
However, if i put it in Wordpress page, the .js file doesn't seems to start up.

I know there are ways to add .js to wordpress header and footer, but i want it in the body of a page. How do i do that?

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/googleformstyler.js"

        form="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeJZ5Es893O4ckhi8-aTOZQe4js9_q2DO1I4pBHT_ENXIpyXg/viewform?embedded=true">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not want to load it in the header/footer? The excerpt below is from the link provided also below. Enqueuing scripts using the following code is the preferred method for wordpress.

You can use `wp_enqueue_script()`.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    $handle, 
    $src = '',
    $deps = array(), 
    $ver = false, 
    $in_footer = false );
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

> Links a script file to the generated page at the right time according to the script dependencies, if the script has not been already included and if all the dependencies have been registered. You could either link a script with a handle previously registered using the `wp_register_script()` function, or provide this function with all the parameters necessary to link a script.
> **This is the recommended method of linking JavaScript to a WordPress generated page.**

This answer is a little more generic as it's difficult to know what you are trying to achieve without more information/code from that .js file. Please feel free to update your question, comment here and the community may be able to assist you in your enquiry further.